# Окно появляется и сразу исчезает

Tags: c++, qt

Я хочу вывести График, после нажатой кнопки. Но у меня окошко появляется и сразу исчезает.

ksp_ecology.cpp:

```
...
    void ksp_ecology::on_pushButton_clicked()
    {

    //![1]
        QLineSeries *series = new QLineSeries();
    //![1]

    //![2]
        series->append(0, 6);
        series->append(2, 4);
        series->append(3, 8);
        series->append(7, 4);
        series->append(10, 5);
        *series << QPointF(11, 1) << QPointF(13, 3) << QPointF(17, 6) << QPointF(18, 3) << QPointF(20, 2);
    //![2]

    //![3]
        QChart *chart = new QChart();
        chart->legend()->hide();
        chart->addSeries(series);
        chart->createDefaultAxes();
        chart->setTitle("Simple line chart example");
    //![3]

    //![4]
        QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);
        chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    //![4]


    //![5]
        QMainWindow window;
        window.setCentralWidget(chartView);
        window.resize(400, 300);
        window.show();
    //![5]
    }
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нельзя создать в функциях на стеке (`QMainWindow window;`) виджеты, которые после создания будут отображены.

Есть два способа выделять память: на стеке (ваш вариант) и в куче (через оператор new).

В функции вы создаете на стеке виджет и отображаете его, тут же функция завершает работу и ее стек чистится, а вместе со стеком и удаляется виджет.

Решения проблемы:

- Самое простое. У вас класс, а значит, можно вынести переменную из функции в поля класса.

  ksp_ecology.h:

  ```
  class ksp_ecology : public QWidget {
      ...
      private:
          QMainWindow window;
      ...
  }
  ```
- Создание объекта на куче. Тогда самим нужно будет чистить память за виджетом

  ```
  //![5]
      QMainWindow* window = new QMainWindow();
      window->setCentralWidget(chartView);
      window->resize(400, 300);
      window->show();
  //![5]
  ```
- Остановка выполнения кода функции через цикл обработки событий, который завершится с закрытием виджета. В диалогах это сделано через метод [exec](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#exec). Либо это можно сделать самому используя [QEventLoop](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/QEventLoop.html)

Comment: Да я уже нашёл на другом форуме. И спасибо за разъяснения, они полезны) Помечу как правильный ответ, когда это будет доступно